# How to do autoresizecolumns() in a Google Sheets file when data imported from another Google Sheets file is changed

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I'm new to Google Sheets and apps scripts. This is my first ever question. I apologize in advance if I don't get it quite right.

- Google Sheets file `Staff Roster` sheet `Roster` contains names, contact info, and some private data for staff members. It is shared with only executives.
- Google Sheets file `Staff Contacts` sheet `Contacts` is a contact list formatted to work nicely on phones. It contains only name, phone, and email and is shared with all staff members. They have view-only access.
- `Contacts` uses importrange() to import the data it needs from `Roster`.
- When an email address is changed in `Roster`, that change may necessitate widening or narrowing the email address column in `Contacts`.
- I have created an onOpen() function in `Contacts` that resizes columns whenever `Contacts` is opened for editing:

```
function onOpen(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Contacts");
    sh.autoResizeColumns(2,4);
}
```

This works fine, but requires me to open `Contacts` whenever a change is made to `Roster` in order to make sure columns are widened or narrowed if needed.

Question: Is there a way to trigger a script in `Contacts` when a change is made in `Roster`? There are other columns with the same issue; I have simplified by mentioning only email.

Research: I have read about a dozen posts that seem related, but I haven't found one that answers this particular question. This has to be a common question. I'm probably just not using the correct search terms to get the answer because I'm so new to apps scripts.

Comment: I'd like to welcome you to Web Apps and thank you for the effort you invested in your question.  It was very clear and detailed.  **A-** (half mark deductions for unnecessary meta-commentary at the start and end)  What a great first post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use Installable Trigger

Instead of using the [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) `onOpen(e)` bound to `Staff Contacts`, use an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) in `Staff Roster` to make the change in `Staff Contacts` whenever `Staff Roster` is edited.

`SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName("Contacts")` where `id` is the spreadsheet ID of `Staff Contacts` will allow you to access the second spreadsheet from the script.

This approach requires an installed trigger (as opposed to simple) which you can install manually, or install using a function (the approach taken below).

Installed triggers require approving additional authorizations when the trigger is first installed.

### Sample Script

1. The sample script below `resizeContacts(e)` is bound to `Staff Roster` and the trigger is installed by manually running `createEditTrigger()`.
2. Every time the spreadsheet `Staff Roster` is edited, the active sheet is checked to see if it is named `Roster` as well as if any of the edited columns are `2-5`.
3. If both conditions are true, `columns 2-5` (4 columns, starting with column 2), of sheet `Contacts` in the spreadsheet `Staff Contacts`, are resized.

Presumably, you could also manage the data in `Contacts` based on this same trigger rather than using the IMPORTRANGE function as you are currently, thus making the calls for data only when actually necessary (data has changed).

- remember to replace `ssId` with the ID for your `Staff Contacts` spreadsheet.

```
// run this once to install trigger
function createEditTrigger() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('resizeContacts') 
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}

// this is the main function
function resizeContacts(e) {

  const range = e.range;
  const sheetA = range.getSheet().getSheetName();
  const start = range.getColumn();      // first column
  const count = range.getNumColumns();  // column count

  // Staff Roster info
  const nameA = "Roster";        // sheet name to match 
  const match = [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ];  // any one column to match
    
  // Staff Contacts info
  const ssId = "1Veb5WQf0erfghCV4YkmPcjtd5AswVr0kHIZt-Lg9AI";
  const size = { c: 2, n: 4 };  // resize start 'c'olumn and 'n'umber
  const nameB = "Contacts";

  if (sheetA == nameA) {

    // all edited column numbers 
    const cols = Array(count).fill().map((e, i) => i + start);
      
    // check if any of match in cols
    if (match.some(c=> cols.indexOf(c) >= 0)) {  

      // open 'Contacts' for resizing       
      const sheetB = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(nameB);
      sheetB.autoResizeColumns(size.c, size.n);

      }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Blindspots for this help, especially for going to the trouble to write a script. I'll give this a try sometime this week and report back.

Comment: Again, thank you @Blindspot. Your solution worked perfectly. Being new to Google Sheets, I'm pleasantly surprised that such a thing can be done. I haven't done the importrange() fix yet because there's more complexity than I showed in my question (wanted to keep it simple). Because these sheets will be installed as a package by multiple groups, I wanted to save them from running the script to install the trigger, so I put it within an onOpen function. Would it be appropriate for me to use "Answer Your Question" to show this refinement? I don't want to take away from the excellence of yours.

Comment: Of course!  I'm interested to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @Blindspots is the one to look at. This is just an additional tidbit to share. The spreadsheet in question will be distributed to various recipients on an ongoing basis and I didn't want each recipient to have to understand about installing the trigger, so I added this code (I subscribe to the else-less, early-return coding style):

```
function onOpen(e)
{
  const trigger = "rosterChange";
  const triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  for (let i=0; i<triggers.length; i++) {
    if (triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == trigger) {
      return;
    }
  }

  // Create the trigger.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  ScriptApp.newTrigger(trigger) 
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onChange()
      .create();
}
```